# What happens when you combine git merge and rebase?

Tags: git, merge, rebase

An argument against git rebase one could make is that it is a more complex process than merge, and if multiple developers are sharing a feature branch, midstream rebases mean all other developers must delete their local branch and get a fresh copy from the central repository (or else start using a difference branch).

In the scenario of multiple devs sharing a branch then, git merge is an easier workflow. But what about the final merge to 'master' when the feature is complete? What happens if instead of using 'rebase' along the way to stay in sync with master, you have been using 'merge', but in the final delivery to 'master' you use an interactive 'rebase' to achieve a clean, linear history and squash uninteresting commits? In particular, what happens when the 'merge' commits are replayed or how does git handle that?

Answer (score 2):

Rebase is only a problem if you end up force pushing, but any operation is a problem if you do that. In your scenario of ending with a rebase into the target branch, git handles that completely fine and just replays the merges, with possible conflicts if the same merge would have conflicted. For the majority of cases, a rebase will only have issues if the corresponding merge would also have had issues.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you would want to avoid rebasing *any* commits that have been made public by pushing. In your case, you can get away with that since you are rebasing a temporary feature branch and since you can communicate very clearly to your team (i.e. those that work on that branch) that the branch essentially disappears once the development is over and those changes have been rebased into your master.

Other than that, there is not really a problem with rebasing a branch that contains merges. The merge commits from master will simply disappear from your rebased branch (since now that you’ve rebased, those changes are already integrated), and you can easily run an interactive merge *afterwards* to further clean up the history.

Comment: The argument that I'm encountering is that it would be difficult to align all the other team members for the rebase. I'm not sure if it would really be an issue or not. They would need to be able to understand and cope with the remote branch suddenly diverging from their local.

Comment: Yes, you would only do this if the branch is really at the end of its life (due to being merged into or rebased onto master). So ideally, following the rebase, you would push the master branch and also delete the remote feature branch. That way, there shouldn’t be a real issue for the other members—apart from general confusion of course, which is why you should communicate this workflow. Other than that, their local (not rebased and outdated) branch won’t break but simply become obsolete.